# displaying 5 images on a single page in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have 5 attachments, whose i want to print on a single page. I am using the following code to display one attachment, now i want to print the other 4 attachments below the first, by giving line breaks.

```
$path1=$rowArray['file1'];
$path2=$rowArray['file2'];
$path3=$rowArray['file3'];
$path4=$rowArray['file4'];
$path5=$rowArray['file5'];

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php printf('<a href="%s">View all Files</a>',$path1); ?></font>

</td>
```

File1 is successfully showing, now how to display the 4 others right below the first one.

Comment: Have you tried *repeating* the line that prints the file?

Comment: @deceze I dnt want to print View all files again and again, i want when user clicks on view all files, list of all images is shown on another page

Comment: Presumably you intended for the `$pathX` lines of PHP to be inside `<?php` tags? Also, it is a good idea to do some web searching first before asking a question - it really does aid the learning process. You'll need a `foreach` loop - see the PHP website.

Answer (score 0):

Add another row (`<tr>`) and display image inside the column (`<td>`).

Comment: how can i, I am very beginner. Please if u tell me a line of code to do that

Comment: Please read the basics of tables here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp . its easy to learn and do it yourself.

Comment: u dnt understand my point, I want to show images on a separate page, by clicking on one link Show all images

Comment: You have not mentioned that you have to show in seerate page. Well if you need it in the seperate page, add the code in the seperate page.

Answer (score 0):

You could just repeat what you are doing for all of the files. Or you can just loop through the array, and forget about the five variables that you have.

```
<?php

foreach($rowArray as $value)
{
?>
    <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php printf('<a href="%s">View all Files</a>', $value); ?></font>
    </td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to show View all files multiple times, I want the functionality of gmail "Show all images". I have used ur above loop, but it doesnot help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply 4 tr tags and in td tag display your files as you are displaying it on first line

Comment: I dont want to do that type of functionality, I want when a user click on show all files, All the files should be displayed on the page. as in gmail View all images it does. Please if u can tell me how can i do that.

Comment: Hanya you can use a div element which will display on click of view all. You can google for how to show hide div using jqyery or javascript. Then inside that div display your other files. Thank :-)